# Hibernate find by enum

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have 2 classes with One-to-Many relationship

```
@javax.persistence.Entity
@TypeDef(name = "InquiryIdType", typeClass = InquiryIdType.class)
public class Inquiry implements Entity
{
    @javax.persistence.Id
    @Type(type = "InquiryIdType")
    @Column(name = "id", columnDefinition = DB_ENTITY_ID_TYPE)
    private InquiryId id;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "conference_session_id", nullable = false)
    private ConferenceSession conferenceSession;

    @Column(name = "state", nullable = false)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private QuizStateType quizStateType;
```

and

```
public enum QuizStateType
{
    IN_PROGRESS(0),
    FINISHED(1),
    NOT_STARTED(2),
    DELETED(3);

    public int value;

    QuizStateType(int value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

I need to find "Inquiry" by the Conference session Id_id and QuizStateType (is Deleted). I try, but swears at the context.

> nested exception is
> org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No
> property is found for type QuizStateType! Traversed path:
> Inquiry.quizStateType.

```
public interface InquiryRepository extends JpaRepository<Inquiry, UUID>
{

    List<Inquiry> findByConferenceSession_idAndQuizStateTypeIs_DELETED  (UUID conferenceSessionId);

}
```

Comment: The problem seems to be with Spring figuring out that _DELETED is meant to be used for the AndQuizStateTypeIs part of your query, so have you tried passing in the QuizStateType.DELETED as a parameter instead of trying to make it a literal within the query? "findByConferenceSession_idAndQuizStateType(UUID conferenceSessionId, QuizStateType quizStateType)"?

Comment: @Chris Now i do
```    List<Inquiry> findByConferenceSession_idAndQuizStateTypeNot(UUID conferenceSessionId, QuizStateType quizStateType);
```

but my idea was that I didn't pass the QuizStateType parameter. Because in my case it is always DELETE